# How to add Kurdish language in Wagtail Localize?

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-localize

I tried using Kurdish as a new language in wagtail , but it kept redirecting to "/en/ku" perhaps because the only locals accessible are BCP-47 language tags. Is there a way to add Kurdish as a new language in wagtail?

i tried wagtail localize and simple translation